# how to get parsley.js to validate if one of the fields has number with a with a minimum value equal to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have Adults, Children and Babies fields on my form. All these 3 fields have a default value which is 0. I am using [parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) to validate the form. I need parsley to validate if at least one of the fields has a value greater than 0. It's should validate the form if one of the fields is bigger then 0. If not it should give an error when trying to submit. I used [this](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/events.html) example from the parsley offical website.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <input  type="text" name="nAdults" id="nAdults" value="0" data-parsley-group="block1" class="form-control " />

    <input  type="text" name="nChildren" id="nChildren" value="0" data-parsley-group="block2" class="form-control "/> 

    <input  type="text" name="nBabies" id="nBabies" value="0" data-parsley-group="block3" class="form-control " /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            //parsley validate
            var form = $('#{{ $pageModule }}FormAjax'); 
            form.parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
            var ok = formInstance.isValid({group: 'block1', force: true}) || formInstance.isValid({group: 'block2', force: true}) || formInstance.isValid({group: 'block3', force: true});
            $('.invalid-form-error-message').html(ok ? '' : 'You must fill at least one of the Adult, Child or FOC Fields!').toggleClass('filled', !ok);
            if (!ok)
            formInstance.validationResult = false;
            });
            //form submit
            form.on('submit', function(e) {
                var f = $(this);
                f.parsley().validate();
                if (f.parsley().isValid()) {
                    var options = { 
                        dataType:      'json', 
                        beforeSubmit :  showRequest,
                        success:       showResponse  
                    }  
                    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
                    return false;
                }
                else    { 
                    return false; }
                    e.preventDefault();
            }); 
        </script>
```

I would appreciate if you can show me how to validate these 3 fields. When I write

`data-parsley-min="1"` it expects all the field to have a minimum value. But I need only one field to have minimum value "1".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsley.js check if one of the fields has a value greater than or equal to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133827/parsley-js-check-if-one-of-the-fields-has-a-value-greater-than-or-equal-to-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write custom validator. [Here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html) can you find a good example, how to do this.

[my own working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tookie009/rjb7kb1n/5/) (see console)

```
// bind event after form validation
$.listen('parsley:form:validated', function(ParsleyForm) {
// We only do this for specific forms
if (ParsleyForm.$element.attr('id') == 'myForm') {
    var combinations = ParsleyForm.$element.find('input')
    ,counter=0;
    $.each($('input'),function(){
        counter+=($(this).val());
    });
    if(counter>0) 
        ParsleyForm.validationResult = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I get an error `Unexpected token else`.

Comment: Woaww! Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted to do. So, `data-parsley-group` doesn't have any functionality. Also why do we use `$.listen` ?

Comment: with `$.listen` parsley is listening to specified events. In this case to form validate.